Jenkins automatically approve script using configuration-as-code plugin for setup
I use configuration-as-code plugin to set up my Jenkins. The setup works and I see my job inside the Jenkins GUI.
If I now run it, I get the following error:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.UnapprovedUsageException: script not yet approved for use

I know if I manually approve the job, I can run it.
But how can I automatically approve these jobs?

You can use Configuration-as-Code JCasC Plugin to automate the approving process.

First manually approve the script using Jenkins UI.
Approved Script will be added to ScriptApproval.xml file in Home directory
Include XML file in JCasC YAML file as an unclassified section
Now in order to automate the approval process you can use groovy script in initialization process that approves certain scripts and signatures by adding them directly into the security settings of jenikins


import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.approvalProcess;
def approvalProcess= approvalProcess.get();
approvalProcess.approveSignature('YourScriptsSingature');
approvalProcess.save();


Can you add how I add the XML to JCasC so it's automatically approved? I do not understand why I have to include an XML file whereas you pasted a Groovy file?
